# Difference between wide-grip lat pull-downs and wide-grip pull-ups

Tags: exercise-equipment, pull-ups, upper-body-workout

I have a workout plan based on the use of traditional equipment, than includes both of these exercises. TRX is, I guess, the most known brand of straps suspended from the ceiling or wall. Pull-ups, for example, I have two handles hanging down from the ceiling, about 2' apart.

I'd like adapt it to the use of a TRX as much as possible and wanted to understand how these two exercises differ in what they target.

Comment: Then pull ups on the TRX are fine. In fact, they would be superior to the pull down machine.

Answer (score 1):

I actually just read an article that talked about wide-grip pull-ups  but it said that pull ups recruit a large amount of muscle fibers from many different muscle groups, more than alot of other workouts. I can't find the article atm, but if I can find the article, I will post it. I think this is a big difference between the exercises, although in the article they didn't explicitly say which exercises the pull-ups beat out in terms of muscle fiber recruitment. In other words pulls-ups = ultimate back shredders.

Comment: You wouldn't have happened to have ever found that article to add a link to, would you?

Answer (score 1):

I think a wide grip pull-up is superior to a lat pull-down because you are not seated (better back posture) and there is not shakiness due to the cable-line moving to the whims of your untrained muscles. When you do a pull-up, everything is upright and your body has ot conform. With a lat-pull down... you're seated, the thing that goes over your legs helps you pull more wieght (you use your hipflexors or leg muscles), back posture is questionable, the cable allows the bar to move as you do, even your alignment left-to-right can be off. I have no idea what TRX is, if it's closer to a wide-grip pull than a lat-pull down, that's better.